# Contact details not showing user information

Tags: 2013, user-profile, contacts, user-information-list

I've got a standard Contact Details web part on a page, when I add some users as the contact the web part refreshes with no change, yet other users are fine.

I've checked the problem users exist in both the User Profiles and the User list in the site collection but am at a loss as to why for user 1 the contact details web part works, but User 2 they web part returns to its original state.

I cant see anything in the logs for this unfortunately.

Any ideas?

Comment: This might be a long shot, but in SharePoint 2003 I remember some web parts needed the user to have visited the site collection / site / page before the information was available. In other words, ask User 2 to visit the page.

Comment: I think thats correct - I added the user manually to the visitors group, a new entry was made in the User Profile List and I was able to add the user in the contact details web part.  Can you add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I've added it as an answer. Who would have thought an issue from SharePoint 2003 could be relevant in SharePoint 2013 :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a long shot, but in SharePoint 2003 I remember some web parts needed the user to have visited the site collection / site / page before the information became available.

In other words, ask User 2 to visit the page.

Comment: Wow. Adding to Visitors group solved the problem (SP2013).

Comment: In my case I added the user in question to the members group. SharePoint 2013 on premises.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SharePoint online and following @heinrich-ulbricht suggestion, I added the user to Members group and it fixed the issue.

Once the issue is resolved, I removed the user from the members group and nothing reverted back :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem came up after migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. The contact detail web part was not saving the user name - though resolving it correctly. Deleting the webpart and adding it again fixed it.